# What is a high speed sub-sampling library for big point cloud?

Tags: c++, computer-vision, point-cloud-library, resampling

I need a c++ library which creates samples from a large point cloud via Poisson or spatial method because these methods avoid of degrading structure, holding overlap points and making step in slop terrain in comparision with VoxelGrid and Random methods. I know that [VCGLIB](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/vcglib), [CCLib](http://www.danielgm.net/cc/doc/CCLib/html/annotated.html), [PDAL](http://www.pdal.io/tutorial/dart-throwing.html), [CGAL](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_processing_3/#title10), [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx) are five suitable libraries but I cannot implement a main() method which call subsampling easily. Can you suggest an independent library which gets a big point cloud and makes samples by Poisson or Spatial method?

Answer (score 2):

The Point Cloud Library allows you to do that fairly quickly and easily. It offers a few different methods for sub-sampling point clouds.

- [UniformSampling](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_uniform_sampling.html#details), that creates a 3D voxel grid over the input data and approximates all the points in a voxel with their centroid. This approach is a bit slower than approximating them with the center of the voxel, but it represents the underlying surface more accurately. This is the same approach as their VoxelGrid, which has an example [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/voxel_grid.php).
- [RandomSampling](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_random_sample.html#details), that applies a random sampling with uniform probability.
- [NormalSpaceSampling](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_normal_space_sampling.html#details), applies samples so that normals are distributed as uniformly as possible.

Comment: Many thanks Dexter. I examined PCL with a Stress test and it could not load big data with more than 4Gbyte volume. My data file is 13 Gbyte. Now I can load data by another library but I need a library which creates sample from loaded points.